# What are replacements for obsoleted QCameraControl, QMediaControl, QMediaService like classes?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

According to the following Qt 5.15 pages at qt.io, the `QCameraControl`, `QMediaControl`, `QMediaService` classes are obsolete:

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcameracontrol.html
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediacontrol.html
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaservice.html

Unfortunately, I don't see mention of replacements for these however.

I'm of the understanding that these (and similar classes) were available for writing back-end support for cameras that aren't already supported by Qt.

My question then is: in Qt 5.15 and newer, what Qt classes, functions, or other mechanisms can/should be used instead to provide support for cameras that Qt doesn't already support?